# Why are there some constraints on linearity of expectation?

Tags: probability, integration, expectation

I'm quoting from [here](http://goodfeli.github.io/dlbook/contents/prob.html):

> Expectations are linear, for example, $ E[αf(x) +βg(x)] =αE[f(x)]
>  +βE[g(x)],$ when α and β are ﬁxed (not random and not depending on x).

My question about contraints on expectation property. It is clear to me that $ α  $ and $ β$ should not depend on $ x$, however I haven't understand why they can not be a random variable which are drawn from a distribution that is independent from distribution of $ x$. Is there a special propert of integration that doesn't allow the random variables to taken out of integration without changing the remaining part of it?

Comment: Constant means constant with respect to x, so if you have something dependent upon a variable independent from x, you can factor as you like.

Comment: @AdamHughes I see, but the statement is not clear.

Comment: I mean, true, but one doesn't always present things in full generality in every context. I don't tell calculus students what differential forms are, and one typically doesn't expose students immediately to the full generality of linearity of expectation, even if it happens to be true, as in this case. Remember:  absence of a statement doesn't mean it's not true, just that it's not being used at that moment in that context.

Comment: I say that the statement is clear and that the coefficients of the **linear combination** must be scalars. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by the core idea. The linearity of the expectation can be formulated in a more general way as:

> Let $X_1, X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be random variables and $a_1, a_2,\ldots,a_n$ are scalars. Then $E[a_1X_1+a_2X_2+\cdots+a_nX_n] = a_1E[X_1]+a_2E[X_2]+\cdots+a_nE[X_n]$.

From this definition of linearity we have two main points:

- The $X_i$'s **doesn't have to be independent** (one constraint less!)
- The $a_i$'s are [scalars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_(mathematics)), **not random variables**.

Linearity of the expectation comes from the [linearity of the integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity_of_integration) (summation) and you would see that this in turn is related to the important concept of a [linear combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_combination), where the coefficients of the combination are scalars.

Now, suppose that we insist in using independent random variables instead of scalars as coefficients of the linear combination. Let's explore what are actually the properties that we would use with your definition.

Let me denote $f(X)$ as $X_1$ and $g(X)$ as $X_2$.
Let $A$ and $B$ be random variables independent of $X$ and $Y = AX_1+BX_2$. Let $W = AX_1$ and $Z=BX_2$. We have then $Y = W + Z$. How do we compute $E[Y]$? Let's see:

\begin{align}
E[Y] &= \iint (w+z)f_{W,Z}(w,z)dwdz\\
     &= \iint wf_{W,Z}(w,z)dwdz + \iint zf_{W,Z}(w,z)dwdz\\
     &= \int w \left(\int f_{W,Z}(w,z)dz\right) dw + \int z \left(\int f_{W,Z}(w,z)dw\right) dz\\
     &= \int w f_{W}(w) dw + \int z f_{Z}(z) dz\\
     &= E[W] + E[Z],
\end{align}

where in the second inequality we applied the **linearity** property of the integral, in the fourth one we compute the marginal PDF of one variable from the integration of the joint PDF over the other random variable and in the last one we use the definition of expected value.

Now, how do we compute $E[W]$?

\begin{align}
E[W] = E[AX_1] &= \iint \alpha x_1f_{A,X_1}(\alpha,x_1)d\alpha dx_1\\
&= \int \alpha f_{A}(\alpha) d\alpha \int  x_1f_{X_1}(x_1) dx_1 = E[A]E[X_1]
\end{align}
but here we **do not use the linearity** of the integral! What we have used in the second line to factor out is the **independence** of the random variables and a corollary of the [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem)!

So, to get the result

$$E[Y] = E[A]E[f(X)]+E[B]E[g(X)],$$

what we are actually applying is **two** properties of the expected value, the [linearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity) property and the property of the [correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncorrelated_random_variables) (expected value of the product) of independent random variables.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, but I got the answer from Adam's comments. My question based on misunderstanding of the statement quoted in the question. As you also explained, $ α and β$ can be random variables which are drawn from a distribution that is independent from distribution of $ x$.

Comment: I made an edit to my answer. We can factor out because of independence, not because of linearity, I think is important to make emphasis on that, in which are the kind of properties you are using.

Comment: I see it now. Random variable is not like a scalar. It has a distribution and must be integrated jointly with the other random variable. Also if they are independent Fubini's theorem can be used to factor them. I understand where my flow is.  Thanks for the complete answer.